# Binding to Custom Depenendy Property from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

I have implemented a custom DependencyProperty and want to bind to it from XAML. For some reason it does not update when the binding source (MainWindow.Test) is updated. 
The binding source is no DP but triggers a PropertyChanged event. 
The update however works with a non-custom dependency property

**Works**:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" />
```

**Does not work**:

```
<local:DpTest Text="{Binding Test}"/>
```

Any ideas?

---

**Here is the DP implementation**:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
public partial class DpTest : UserControl
{
    public DpTest()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(DpTest), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, textChangedCallBack));

    static void textChangedCallBack(DependencyObject property, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        int x = 5;
    }
}
}
```

**Here is how it is used:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"></TextBlock>
    <local:DpTest Text="{Binding Test}"></local:DpTest>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Update</Button>
</StackPanel></Window>
```

**Code behind with binding source:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string _test;
    public string Test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Test"));
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Test = "Updatet Text";
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you check for binding errors in the output window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do **not** set `DataContext = this;` on `UserControls`, that way all bindings on instances will fail if you assume the `DataContext` to be inherited as this stops it and is quite invisible too. In the UserControl bindings you should either name the control and do `ElementName` bindings or use `RelativeSource`.

e.g.

```
<UserControl Name="control" ...>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=control}"/>
```

```
<UserControl ...>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your window a name and change your binding to the following:
(otherwise the datacontext of the UserControl is used, which is not what you want in your case)

```
...
x:Name="mainWindow">
        <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Height="20" Background="Yellow" Text="{Binding Test}"></TextBlock>
          <local:DpTest Text="{Binding Path=Test, ElementName=mainWindow, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></local:DpTest>
          <Button Click="Button_Click">Update</Button>
```

In you don't have a binding in your UserControl yet then bind the following way:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dpTest, Path=Text,
Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
```

this worked for me..

HTH